# Incorrect Proof for $x^3 = x$ for every $x$ in a ring $R$ then R is commutative.

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification

I am interested in why this proof is wrong since every proof I have seen uses much more knowledge than this and I can't figure out why it is incorrect.

Suppose $x^3 = x$ for every $x \in R$. Then $x = x^{-1}$ and similarly for every $y  \in R$, $y = y^{-1}$. So then $xy \in R$ and $xy = x^{-1}y^{-1}$. Since $yx(x^{-1}y^{-1}$) = $e$, $(yx)^{-1} = (x^{-1}y^{-1})$. Then $xy = (yx)^{-1}$. Since $R$ is closed under multiplication, $yx \in R$ and so by the discussion above, $yx = (yx)^{-1}$. Therefore, $xy = yx$ for all $x$,$y \in R$ which means that $R$ is commutative.

Comment: Why do you assume that $x^{-1}$ exists for all $x\in R$? Well, Wuestenfux (+1) did essentially capture this.

Comment: Actually,is this a great proof that every **group** where $x^3=x$ is commutative!

Comment: I guess this is what happens when someone like me studies groups before rings...

Comment: That's typical of everybody: walk before you crawl, fall down sometimes when you run.  I think it would be a bad idea to learn about rings before learning anything about groups.

Answer (score 4):

Well, if $x^3=x$ in $R$, then by the shortening rule, $x^2=1$. But this only holds if $x$ is not a zero divisor.

Comment: I understand the comment above that the inverse doesn't necessarily exist, but I don't understand this answer.